Submission for UWP App update not possible
I want to update my app and have created a new submission in Partner Central.
Every single item checks out, but the Submit button is greyed out with the error "Please review and address any validation issues before submitting."... there are no errors shown...
Any ideas who I could ask for help?

Same as this question.
You need to check any agreement pending from your end, Go to https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/account/v3/settings/agreements.


Thanks Junjie, that solved the problem. Might I suggest to place a reference to these types of roadblocks in the app submission form, as it does not provide any visible clue on what is holding back the next step. THANKS
